# X1 Carbon: screen flashes when opening

Tags: display, greeter

When I put my laptop to sleep, and then open it later to login, the “unlocked” screen flashes briefly before the login screen takes over. Has anyone else seen this? Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I’ve only seen this when the notebook is connected to an external monitor and the system is trying to work out the display devices 

Comment: It seems to me that this may only be happening when the laptop is not asleep before reopening the lid. If I close the lid and reopen much later, the screen doesn’t flash “unlocked” first but just shows the login screen. I’ll leave this question open for now in case anyone knows why it’s happening.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this with the following system settings. "When lid is closed": "Lock". (Before, I had it set to "Suspend".)

[image: Power Settings]